# GCP Cloudshell Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, storage

I wrote multiple shell scripts to manage gcloud recources using the cloudshell CLI. 
After an SSO integration, this all seem to be deleted.

In Azure I am aware, all the files that gets created via AZ CLI gets stored in a storage disk. 
Does anyone know where the data gets stored when we use the GCP CLI ?

Any ideas or suggestions to make data persistency while using GCP Cloudshell would be appreciated .

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: As per the help center article article about the [working of cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works), cloud Shell provisions 5 GB of free persistent disk storage mounted as your $HOME directory on the virtual machine instance.Unlike the instance itself, this storage does not time out on inactivity. However, if you do not access Cloud Shell regularly, the $HOME directory persistent storage may be recycled. Is this something you are looking for?

Comment: You have 2 accounts, one when you are directly connected to GCP, the second one when you use SSO. The file are still there, but in your first account!

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere . You are right

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation below to check the limitations for GCP Cloud Shell.

https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quotas-limits

By default, it uses persistent disk storage when you activate the Cloud Shell.

https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#persistent_disk_storage